'}' expected when trying redirect my buttons in the sidebar to a different Form
I am getting an '}' expected error on the buttonNamesAndFormNames method. I can seem to be figuring out why it's throwing the error as you can clearly see it at the end of the method. I have included the other methods as I am trying to get my dynamically created buttons to redirect to my DocumentUnderstand form. I want these buttons in my SideBar to redirect to all different forms in VB.NET. I have tried 'Clean' & 'Rebuild', but the error is still there. Any help is greatly appreciated.
    ' Define an array with button names and their corresponding form names
Private buttonNamesAndFormNames() As (buttonName As String, formName As String) = {
    ("Document understanding", "DocUnderstand.vb"),
    ("Button 2", "Form2"),
    ("Button 3", "Form3"),
    ("Button 4", "Form4"),
    ("Button 5", "Form5"),
    ("Button 6", "Form6")
    ' Add more button names and corresponding form names as needed
}

Private Sub SideMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    InitializeDynamicControls()
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeDynamicControls()
    ' Add buttons dynamically based on the buttonNamesAndFormNames array
    For Each pair In buttonNamesAndFormNames
        Dim button As New Button()
        button.Text = pair.buttonName
        button.Dock = DockStyle.Top
        AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf OpenForm
        Panel1.Controls.Add(button)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub OpenForm(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Handle button click event
    Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim index As Integer = -1

    ' Find the index of the clicked button in the buttonNamesAndFormNames array
    For i As Integer = 0 To buttonNamesAndFormNames.Length - 1
        If buttonNamesAndFormNames(i).buttonName = button.Text Then
            index = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' Open the corresponding form based on the index
    If index >= 0 AndAlso index < buttonNamesAndFormNames.Length Then
        Dim formName As String = buttonNamesAndFormNames(index).formName

        ' Assuming that the form files are in the same namespace as SideBar
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(formName) Then
            Dim formInstance As Form = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(formName)), Form)
            formInstance.Show()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid form name or form not found.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid button index.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub


Move the comment you have added after the last tuple somewhere else -- You should probably use generics for this, instead of Activator.CreateInstance()

You keep referring to buttonNamesAndFormNames as a method in your question. It's not. It's a field. That means that what follows between the braces is a single value, not multiple lines of code. You can't stick a comment in the middle of a value. You are doing the equivalent of this:
Private numbers As Integer() = {
    1,
    2,
    3
    'Blah blah
}

and that is exactly the same as this:
Private numbers As Integer() = {1, 2, 3 'Blah blah}

and that is obviously not valid code.
Get that comment out of your value and put it somewhere that comments are valid.

We have a simplified array definition like this:
Dim foo() As String = {
   "a",
   "b",
   "c"
   ' etc
}

One of the things VB.Net is doing here is called Implicit Line Continuation. That is, it's implicitly re-writing the code through a process called lowering to be compatible with older features and continue all on the same line, like this:
Dim foo() As String = { "a", "b", "c" ' etc  }

Now we can clearly see the problem: the comment is hiding the closing brace.
As I think about it, the comment also probably prevents the closing brace from inclusion at all, so it's not even "continued" to the first line, but the compiler finds the error for the missing brace first. Also, the lowering link is talking about the  C# Roslyn re-write, but I believe the VB.Net compiler got similar treatment about the same time.
